# How to get object attributes from a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a class named "admin" in my asp.net C# project.
It is:

```
public class Admin
{  
    private int ID;
    private string FirstName, LastName, IsMainAdmin, Email, Username, 
            Password,BirthDate, EntryDate;  

    public int id
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set { ID = value; }
    }

    public string firstname
    {
        get { return FirstName; }
        set { FirstName = value; }
}

    public string lastname
    {
        get { return LastName; }
        set { LastName = value; }
    }
    .  
    .  
    .
```

After login a session is created like this:

```
Admin admin = isAdmin(username, password);
    if (admin != null)
    {
        **Session.Add("maskanAdmin", admin);**
        Response.Redirect("panel.aspx");
    }
```

In other page i need to get admin's ID from session in code behind section after page request via jquery ajax.
**Please notice that my code behind Method is [WebMethod] that is not supporting Session Object.**
Can i get it? How?

Comment: This is covered in the Session documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: I will tell you something else as well. The class declaration doesn't look good!  private int _id; and `public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id= value; }
    }` or simple `public int ID{get;set;}`. Have a look at [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var adminObj = (Admin)Session["maskanAdmin"];    
if(adminObj != null)
{
    var id = adminObj.id;
    var fname = adminObj.firstname;
}
```

Read more about [Read Values from Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Update**

I am not sure why the question is updated after one hour saying you are using the code in web methods.

However, have a look at [Using ASP.NET Session State in a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx)

Comment: You are accessing a collection lookup by indexer twice. You are also checking for null twice. That is unnecessary. You could simply do: `var adminObj = (Admin)Session["maskanAdmin"]; if (adminObj != null) { ... }`

Comment: @Silvermind: Feel free to edit the answer :) I wasn't exactly sure. That's why checked the both places

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast it back to an `Admin` type object when you retrieve it from the Session:

```
Admin admin = (Admin)Session["maskanAdmin"];
```

Then you can use the properties of the object as normal:

```
if(admin.ID == someOtherID)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Admin variableName = (Admin)Session["maskanAdmin"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var adminObj = Session["maskanAdmin"];
if(adminObj != null)
{
    var admin = (Admin)adminObj;
}
```

Comment: Admin is a class so checking for null is not really necessary before casting.

Comment: @Silvermind - Looks like I learn something new everyday. Just tested it out and you are correct. I was thinking a casting error would occur if adminObj was null and I tried to cast to the Admin object.

Comment: `null` is fixed. Everything that is `null` points to the same location, therefore you do not have to be affraid to cast an object that is nullable to `null` here :). Simple LinqPad example: `object a = null;
 string b = null;
 (a == b).Dump();` // True